# Regex - Insert spaces between parentheses and alphanumeric characters in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to insert spaces between words, numbers, and parentheses. For example i have the string

```
string a = "20and(2and 3)";
```

and i want to have

```
string b = "20 and ( 2 and 3 )";
```

I found this method for inserting spaces between words and numbers, and it works. But it doesn't insert spaces when there are parentheses...

```
b = Regex.Replace(a, "(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])", " ");
```

Can anyone help me with this please...?
Thank You very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this instead:

```
b = Regex.Replace(a, "[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+|[()]", "$0 ");
```

Although this will insert a space at the end as well. If that is a problem, you can just `Trim` the result string:

```
b = Regex.Replace(a, "[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+|[()]", "$0 ").Trim();
```